# CSS file not found when trying to load with django

Tags: css, django

My CSS file i'snt being found I try to load it in and ive tried so many different solutions online in order to fix it and cant seem to figure out why and I also have my static and templates both in the same file as the project along with my manage.py file.

For my Setting file

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles'
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Inside my base html I have

```
{% load static %}

<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The css file can be modified for every template if required -->
    {% block style_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
    {% endblock %}
    <title>Website Homepage Design Prototype #1</title>
```

Comment: Have you added the static urls to your url pattern? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Is this needed ?

Comment: And I had a look at the link mentioned and still unsure as to what is needed to be added in

Answer (score 0):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

add this line below `STATIC_URL` it should surely work